# Pattern matching with more than one match

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Consider the following Scala code.

```
val a = "both"

a match {
    case "both" | "foo" => println ("foo")   // case 1
    case "both" | "bar" => println ("bar")   // case 2
}
```

I would like `match` to work so that if `a == "both"`, Scala will execute both cases. Is this possible or are there any alternatives to achieve what I want?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Match "fallthrough": executing same piece of code for more than one case?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325863/match-fallthrough-executing-same-piece-of-code-for-more-than-one-case)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Standard pattern-matching will always match on only exactly one case. You can get close to what you want by using the fact that patterns can be treated as partial functions (see the [Language Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf), Section 8.5, *Pattern Matching Anonymous Functions*) and by defining your own matching operator, though:

```
class MatchAll[S](scrutinee : =>S) {
  def matchAll[R](patterns : PartialFunction[S,R]*) : Seq[R] = {
    val evald : S = scrutinee
    patterns.flatMap(_.lift(evald))
  }
}

implicit def anyToMatchAll[S](scrut : =>S) : MatchAll[S] = new MatchAll[S](scrut)

def testAll(x : Int) : Seq[String] = x matchAll (
  { case 2 => "two" },
  { case x if x % 2 == 0 => "even" },
  { case x if x % 2 == 1 => "neither" }
)

println(testAll(42).mkString(",")) // prints 'even'
println(testAll(2).mkString(","))  // prints 'two,even'
println(testAll(1).mkString(","))  // prints 'neither'
```

The syntax is slightly off the usual, but to me such a construction is still a witness to the power of Scala.

Your example is now written as:

```
// prints both 'foo' and 'bar'
"both" matchAll (
  { case "both" | "foo" => println("foo") },
  { case "both" | "bar" => println("bar") }
)
```

(**Edit** [huynhjl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/257449/huynhjl) pointed out that he gave a frighteningly similar answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6720205/idiomatic-way-to-convert-a-seqb).)

Comment: This reminds me of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6720205/idiomatic-way-to-convert-a-seqb/6720659#6720659. What's the benefit of the by name `=> S`?

Comment: Wow. I had no idea this was there. Thanks for adding the link. I use the by name argument for the (unlikely) case someone would construct the MatchAll instance before using it, so that the potential effects resulting from the evaluation of the scrutinee appear in the right place.

Answer (score 6):

At risk of being Captain Obvious, in a case like this it would be simplest just to forget pattern matching and use `if`.

```
if (a == "both" || a == "foo") println("foo")
if (a == "both" || a == "bar") println("bar")
```

If the repetition of `a ==` worries you, you could instead write

```
if (Set("both", "foo")(a)) println("foo")
if (Set("both", "bar")(a)) println("bar")
```

using the fact that the `apply` method on `Set` does the same as `contains`, and is a bit shorter.

Answer (score 3):

`match` executes one, and only one, of the cases, so you can't do this as an `or` in the match. You can, however, use a list and `map`/`foreach`:

```
val a = "both"
(a match {
  case "both" => List("foo", "bar")
  case x => List(x)
}) foreach(_ match {
  case "foo" => println("foo")
  case "bar" => println("bar")
})
```

And you're not duplicating any of the important code (in this case the `println`s).

Answer (score 1):

Just match twice:

```
val a = "both"

a match {
    case "both" | "foo" => println ("foo")   // Case 1
}
a match {
    case "both" | "bar" => println ("bar")   // Case 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible way could be:

```
val a = "both"

a match {
  case "foo" => println ("foo")   // Case 1
  case "bar" => println ("bar")   // Case 2
  case "both" => println ("foo"); println ("bar")
}
```